# ASP.NET framework bug

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, debugging

Go into your iis machine level settings and add

```
<deployment retail="true" />
```

As specified in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228298.aspx

Create a new web project, add a label and then the following code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled.ToString();
}

//Result: true
```

**What am I missing?**

**Update:** I updated the value on the 64 and 32 bit versions of the machine config. The server is running IIS7.5. Reboot didn't help.

**Update 2:**

Stepping through V4 of the framework using Reflector I get the following code.

```
public bool IsDebuggingEnabled
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return CompilationUtil.IsDebuggingEnabled(this);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

internal static bool IsDebuggingEnabled(HttpContext context)
{
    return MTConfigUtil.GetCompilationConfig(context).Debug;
}

//Here is where I lose whats going on... Either way, if what Yaur said is correct then
//I believe that value is not only useless but dangerously misleading. 
internal static CompilationSection GetCompilationConfig(HttpContext context)
{
    if (!UseMTConfig)
    {
        return RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(context).Compilation;
    }
    return GetConfig<CompilationSection>(context);
}
```

Either way. What I can confirm is that the functionality does not seem to work.

PS: @Yaur - Yes I have tried changing the value and I am well aware of the alternatives to using this method but the point is that this method is supposed to simplify deployment.

Comment: I'm looking at this a little further, but for now notice that those requirements mention being for IIS6, and the blogpost below is from 2006

Comment: Fair point but notice that, that page is the Framework 4 one. It would be nice if they were specific about whether the "Requirements" were "Minimum requirements" or "Absolute requirements"

Comment: Yeah, I know. So the "retail" trick applies to compiled binaries, but doesn't seem to affect the current context, still reflecting ... it only seems to affect traces, not the debug stuff. Granted, you gotta have debug for trace, but you don't gotta have trace for debug

Comment: the next thing to try is to step into it with reflector pro and see what its doing at run time.  I can't do this till tomorrow night though.

Answer (score 8):

According to : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/442448.aspx, it should force :

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="false">
</system.web>
```

Have you rebooted your server ?
Which machine.config did you edit ?

Comment: Thats the point, my understanding is its supposed to override the web.config settings. No?

Comment: From mdsn : "When retail is set to true, ASP.NET disables **certain** configuration settings such as trace output, custom errors, and debug capabilities."

Comment: Right? "and debug capabilities" exactly!

Comment: Yes, but maybe it doesn't act on this specific property : HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled, hence the **certain** and my answer.

Comment: Well then either the declaration is broken or that property. Either way, somethings fishy... (Maybe its just the system I am testing on, I will try another soon)

Answer (score 7):

Looking at HttpContext in reflector all this method does is to load the value found in the compilation section.  So set that as mathieu suggested and you you should be golden.
Also (if you care) it will throw an exception if running under mono.

from the *2.0 version* of System.Web:

it calls

`CompilationUtil.IsDebuggingEnabled(this);`

which calls

`RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(context).Compilation.Debug;`

Compilation.Get returns

`(CompilationSection) this.GetSection("system.web/compilation", typeof(CompilationSection), ResultsIndex.Compilation);`

the 4.0 version is a bit different... based on what I can tell it looks the "extra stuff" is multitargeting support.  So if you are targeting .net 4 and setting `<compilation debug="false">` didn't work try following the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398791.aspx) and use

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
</compilation>
```

instead

Comment: Looking at the code through reflector myself I am not convinced you are correct. It looks to me like it is accessing some sort of "global compilation state" object (which seems more logical to me). I will look further and post back.

Comment: @Maxim Gershkovich more to the point have you tried changing this value and seen it not work?

Comment: @Maxim Gershkovich updated the answer to reflect .net4 options